# I am using Pytest Selenium_Python and I wnat to take user input, but when I used the input function in that case my Pytest framwork not allowing

Tags: pytest

My Code is

```
 def LoginPage(self, InputUID, InputPass):
        try:
            User_name = "//input[@id='Email']"
            Passwrd = "//input[@id='Password']"
            captcha = "//input[@id='CaptchaInputText']"
            for i in range(0, 3):
                if i == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                             "//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/*[1]").click()
```

Error

Please Enter Captcha:
test_Vendor_Registration_Test.py:None (test_Vendor_Registration_Test.py)
test_Vendor_Registration_Test.py:8: in 
class Vendor_Reg_Test:
test_Vendor_Registration_Test.py:13: in Vendor_Reg_Test

I am using Pytest Selenium_Python and I wnat to take user input, but when I used the input function in that case my Pytest framwork not allowing